# How to install Facebook Gameroom on WINE?

Tags: wine, games, facebook

Facebook Gameroom is a Windows app for games that can be downloaded from: https://www.facebook.com/gameroom/download/

I have tried to install it with Ubuntu 18.04 default Wine (1.6) and also with Winehq from upstream (https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).

I have installed and tested dotnet 45, 46 and 461 with winetricks.

The "FacebookGameroom.exe" installer get stuck with a message that says "Connecting" when I run `wine FacebookGameroom.exe`.

Interestingly I get more progress running natively with mono `mono FacebookGameroom.exe`, it goes through "Connecting" > "Downloading" > "Installing" but then get stuck too.

Comment: This worked for me (Windows 10)
Right click FacebookGameroom installer and select Troubleshoot Compatibility.
Follow instructions to fix compatibility issue.
Test run the program to make sure it works.
Save settings.

Comment: You are using Windows 10 or WINE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install Winehq following the instructions of https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

   ```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
   wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
   sudo apt-key add winehq.key
   sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
   ```
2. Install winetricks following instructions of https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks

   ```
   cd "${HOME}/Downloads"
   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
   chmod +x winetricks
   ```
3. Make a wine container for example

   ```
   mkdir ~/Wine/gameroom && cd ~/Wine/gameroom
   ```
4. Run `export WINEARCH=win32` and `export WINEPREFIX=/home/$USER/Wine/gameroom`
5. Run `winetricks` and install dotnet452
6. Run `wine uninstaller` and install "FacebookGamesArcade.msi"
   (obs.: in order to download this file one will have to repeat steps 1 to 5 making another container and use winetricks to install ole32.dll. Don't install it in the same container you plan to install FacebookGamesArcade.msi because then it won't load. Then run `wine FacebookGameroom.exe`. Then search inside ../drive_c/users/$USER/Temp/something for the installer "FacebookGamesArcade.msi").
7. Open the app by running

   ```
   wine ~/Wine/gameroom/drive_c/users/$USER/Local\ Settings/Application\ Data/Facebook/Games/FacebookGameroom.exe
   ```

The Gameroom will start and would look like:

[image]